# PowerShell -file command with nonstatic filename

Tags: powershell

I am running powershell.exe with the -file filename command
It works if I set a static filename, but i need it to point to the current user.
I tried using

```
-File C:\%username%\restofpath
-File C:\$username\restofpath
```

but none open the .ps1 file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As for this:

```
-File C:\%username%\restofpath
-File C:\$username\restofpath
```

The first one is a `cmd.exe` batch file formatted command, and as written it should fail in the PS shell.

The second is not how you are for the current username unless you have set that $username variable elsewhere.

The PowerShell built-in environment variables will show you what you can get.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'env:\'
```

You must use the full name to dynamically get/use those as a variable in your code.

```
$env:USERNAME
$env:USERPROFILE
$env:USERDOMAIN
$env:USERDNSDOMAIN
etc...
```

So then this:

```
$env:USERNAME
$env:USERPROFILE
$env:USERDOMAIN
# Results
<#
WDAGUtilityAccount
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount
BD505E85-E891-4
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\*"

# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                              
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                              
...                                                                          
d-r---         11/4/2022   3:18 PM                Documents                                                                         
d-r---         11/4/2022   3:18 PM                Downloads                                                                         
...
#>
```